# testing if a controller method (with Guid as parameter) calls repository method (also with guid as parameter)

Tags: asp.net-mvc, unit-testing, asp.net-mvc-4, testing, rhino-mocks

I'm trying to write a test method for one of my controller methods.
Here is the controller method

```
public ActionResult LicenseDetails(Guid id)
    {
        var licenseDetails = _businessUnitRepository.GetLicenseDetails(id);
        return View(licenseDetails);
    }
```

and here is the test i've written to check if it calls the method in repository.

```
 [TestMethod]
    public void ModuleDetails_Action_Calls_GetLicenseDetails()
    {
        _mockBusinessUnitRepository.GetLicenseDetails(Arg<Guid>.Is.Anything);

        _controller.LicenseDetails(Arg<Guid>.Is.Anything);

        _mockBusinessUnitRepository.AssertWasCalled(x=>x.GetLicenseDetails(Arg<Guid>.Is.Anything));
    }
```

I'm getting error right now that says:
Test method **AdminPortal.Tests.Controller_Test.Customer.BusinessUnitControllerTests.ModuleDetails_Action_Calls_GetLicenseDetails threw exception: 
System.InvalidOperationException: Use Arg ONLY within a mock method call while recording. 1 arguments expected, 3 have been defined.**

Ps: I'm using Rhino mock and i'm new to this testing thing

Answer (score 0):

I think it is complaining about this line:

```
_controller.LicenseDetails(Arg<Guid>.Is.Anything);
```

Instead of doing that, try passing in an actual value:

```
_controller.LicenseDetails(Guid.NewGuid());
```

Comment: still throws error says: **Test method AdminPortal.Tests.Controller_Test.Customer.BusinessUnitControllerTests.ModuleDetails_Action_Calls_GetLicenseDetails threw exception: 
System.InvalidOperationException: Use Arg<T> ONLY within a mock method call while recording. 1 arguments expected, 2 have been defined.**